# Jasper Reports - Cannot Find Report

Tags: pdf-generation, jasper-reports, report

I am running Jasper Reports with Apache Ant. When I go to generate a sample report into a pdf I run this:

```
root@server~$ /home/user/apache-ant-1.8.2/bin/ant pdf
Buildfile: /home/user/jasperreports-4.0.2/demo/samples/table/build.xml

pdf:

pdf:
     [java] Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: TableApp
     [java] Java Result: 1

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 1 second
```

The problem is, I cannot find where that PDF went to, if the file even converted into a PDF at all, really. I ran the "find" command and no luck. This is a demo report called "Table" in the Jasper Report's demo directory. The build.xml file in the sample reports directory has this:

```
<target name="pdf" description="Generates a PDF version of the report by converting the .jrprint file.">
    <ant dir="../" target="pdf"/>
</target>
```

That tells me that it should convert this report into PDF and shoot the file to the parent directory. I made a directory called PDF and use absolute path to shoot it there and all that it did was shoot a build.xml file with no data to it...

The PDF is nowhere to be found. What I am missing here?

Thanks for any help, the jasperforge forum isn't responding to my thread. I don't think this is a very complex problem, so hopefully I can get some help... this is my last step with Jasper!

Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

[java] Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: TableApp

this error means that you should have  a main() method in TableApp.